# How to get the laucher button in a bean validation method

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I need to do some validation depending of the button clicked, but I can't find a way of getting that button inside the validation method in the bean. If I could get the button maybe could compare with a defined attribute inside. So this is what I get:

```
<af:button id="btnSearch">
  <f:attribute name="action" value="search"/>
</af:button>

<af:inputText id="itSearch" validator="#{pageFlowScope.mbCustom.customValidation}">
</af:inputText>
```

In the bean:

```
public void customValidation(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uIComponent, Object object) {
     UIComponent button = //button that trigger the validation
    String validationError = "";
    if("search".equals(button.getAttributes().get("action")){
        validationError ="Validation Button1";
    }else if("other".equals(button.getAttributes().get("action")){
        validationError ="Validation Button2";
    }
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                                  validationError,
                                                  null));

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to find out what button was clicked? Action won't tell you this. And Action should be used for navigation only. You should use ActionListener event and the ActionListener Event object returned to the method will have the component object that initiated the event. I would have an ActionListener event for each button that can be clicked and in the method that is called simply set the component id for the button being clicked.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check that. What I trying to do is to use components validators for all the validations in the page, and the only way to do that is knowing in the method the button that trigger the action, since some component have different validations depending of who is clicked.